# How To Add OR/AND To rendered apex VisualForce

Tags: apex, profile, visualforce

How can I add multiple profiles to the below code?  I get an error when I attempt to add more than one output panel that has showChatter="true".  It errors with a message that says: Error: Only one Chatter-related component can be specified per page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'}">
    <apex:detail subject="{!Lead.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="true"  /> </apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'Force'}" >
    <apex:detail subject="{!Lead.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="false"  /> </apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'Salesforce 44 Call Center'}" >
    <apex:detail subject="{!Lead.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="false"  /> </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

I want to add more than one profile to the showchatter="true" output panel using a OR.

Comment: You should set the `rendered` property on the `<apex:detail>` tags themselves.

Comment: Could you give an example using the code above?  I tried your instruction but I then get the following error:  Error: The value of attribute "rendered" associated with an element type "apex:detail" must not contain the '<' character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `||` ('OR') statement inside the `rendered` tag:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' || $Profile.Name = 'Force' || $Profile.Name = 'Salesforce 44 Call Center'}">
    <apex:detail subject="{!Lead.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="{!$Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'}"  /> </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think it should be `showChatter="{!$Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'}"`.

Comment: You can do the same with the and operator `&&` and not operator `!` as well. About the only thing I'd try to avoid is having a 'not' be the first thing in an expression, because it's very easy to gloss over the second `!` in `{!!field__c}` (or mistake it for double negation)

Comment: @Derek That's the primary reason I tend to just use `NOT`, `AND`, and `OR` functions.

Comment: You are right @AdrianLarson, I overlooked the difference between the 3 panels. Not the first time you correct me ;-). Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianLarson Certainly an option. I personally find it harder to read Polish Notation than Infix notation though.

Comment: Thanks Guy!  I was putting the || in the wrong spot and wasn't typing the $Profile.Name= for each entry.  I was writing as in a formula for a field/workflow

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Guy!

I wanted to have two Output Panels, to easily track. One for Chatter True and One for Chatter False.

I used the following and this works too:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' || $Profile.Name = 'Customer Service' || $Profile.Name = 'Force Manager' || $Profile.Name = 'Manager'  || $Profile.Name = 'SuperUser'}" >
    <apex:detail subject="{!Lead.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="true"  />
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'Force' || $Profile.Name = 'Salesforce 44 Call Center'}" >
    <apex:detail subject="{!Lead.Id}" inlineEdit="true" showChatter="false"  />
</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```